# async method not blocking on desktop but blocking on server?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I made a simple async method to call an SQL stored procedure asynchronously.

In my console program, I am calling this method 1000 times in a loop, and sleep for 1ms (Thread.Sleep) between each call.
I start a StopWatch before entering the loop, and stop it when exiting the loop, and display the time spent in the loop.

On my development machine (Win7 - VS 2012 RC), I can see what I was expecting to see :

```
Completed in 1006 ms
```

This seems logical, considering that the call to the async method returns almost immediately (when reaching the first `await` keyword), so there is just a small overhead (6ms) incured while executing the code before the await.

However when I run the exact same code on a server machine (Win2008 R2 SP1) on which I have installed .NET Framework 4.5 RC the code is running fine however the execution time is far from the one I am expecting, in no comparison with the one obtained when running the program on my development machine :

```
Completed in 15520 ms
```

Meaning that somehow the async method being called is not really called asynchronously and the first await seems to somehow block ?

Here is the code of the async method I am calling :

```
public async void CallSpAsync()
{
  var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_mysp");
  {  
     var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
     {
       cmd.Connection = conn;
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       [...Filling command parameters here - nothing interesting...]

       await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();                    
       await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

       cmd.Dispose();
       cmd.Connection.Dispose();
     }
  }
}
```

And here is the main program testing code (loop) :

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   CallSpAsync();
   Thread.Sleep(1);
}
sw.Stop();
```

I am running the exact same executable (console program compiled in Release) on both machines.

I am tyring to figure out why the method is not truly called asynchronously when running the program on the server machine.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

**EDIT**

The problem has nothing to do with async/await which is working just fine, but is due to the timer resolution (used by StopWatch) on the server being 15 time less than on my workstation. The code is not running slower at all, it's just the resolution of the timer which is leading to incorect elapsed time computation.

See answer from James Manning below.

Comment: You are running a console program in both cases?

Comment: Try breaking in the debugger a few times and see where it stops on your server machine.

Comment: Parts of some async methods are still run synchronously (especially DNS lookups).

Comment: @usr : I am indeed running the same exact console program (compiled in Release) in both cases with no debugger attached. And unfortunately the server machine is not configured to allow remote debugging, I'll do this in last resort if nobody has an idea ;)

Comment: @SLaks : Indeed, but this is not the problem here. The problem is that on my desktop development machine the method is run fully asynchronously, whereas on a server machine the method is run synchronously (or partially asynchronously).

Comment: What happens if you measure just the `Thread.Sleep()` without the async method call?

Comment: Can you post the CPU specs (number of physical cores, speed, and whether or not hyper-threading is enabled)?

At risk of sounding really obvious - is it possible that the scheduler is doing more in parallel on your workstation than on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a function of the timer resolution on the server machine.  Check the ClockRes utility. You can get some more details in [my comment on *High accuracy DateTime.UtcNow*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2012/05/16/high-precision-datetime-utcnow-on-windows-server-os.aspx).

Comment: Seems like it indeed !
Running the clockres utility on my workstation gives me a max/min/current of 15.600/0.500/1.000 (ms).
Running the clockres utility on the server gives me a max/min/current of 15.625/0.500/15.625 (ms).
What the ... ? 
So it is indeed the issue. Thanks a LOT for your answer, I could have turned in circle for hours. So it has nothing to do with async/await and it doesn't mean that the code run slower but just the timer resolution is not correct. Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: @Stephen : Yes but it's there for the purpose of the specific benchmark demo. Any way to change the timer resolution on the server ?

Comment: @darkey: Not to my knowledge. Microsleeping just isn't that portable. What exactly are you trying to show with your demo?

Comment: @Stephen : After some thinking I can indeed get rid of the Thread.Sleep(1) while achieving the same demonstration. It was kind of a stupid idea but at least it allowed me to discover something new concerning timer resolution ;) Thanks

Comment: @darkey: After more research it turns out [you can change the system timer resolution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxtoolsdev/thread/8aea13d9-35f1-4b66-a5b4-726651d985f7) (by P/Invoking an undocumented function). I still wouldn't recommend it though, especially on a server. :)

Comment: Thanks for your research, will try it out then, this is a development/test server not a production one so not risking a lot there ;)